# Why does [{"value":"tag1"} turns into [object Object] when logged?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string, object

On my node.js server I have the following code:

```
var tags = [{"value":"tag1"},{"value":"tag2"}];
console.log("tags: " + tags);
```

I expected the console to say this:

```
tags: [{"value":"tag1"},{"value":"tag2"}]
```

But instead got this:

```
tags: [object Object],[object Object]
```

Why does this happen? It's causing problems in my code because I'm trying to access the values but can't.

Comment: using the `+` operator to concatenate an object with a string is like calling `'string' + obj.toString()`, which `({}).toString()` is `[object Object]`. Js attempts to convert the second item in the operation to the type of the first item, a string, hence why you're not seeing the contents of the array but rather `[object Object]`.

Comment: If you want to log it, do this - console.log({tags:tags}) rather than console.log("tags: " + tags). in this case it is trying to add a string to object thus giving you unexpected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a concatenated string using the `+` operator, the `.toString()` method is called on the non-string parts to convert them to readable strings – and this method returns `[object Object]` for plain objects.

If you want to see the actual content of the array, use :

- `console.log("tags: ", tags);` (when used in the browser's console, allows for an "interactive" log : you'll be able to click on the array and unfold its content) ;
- or `console.log("tags: " + JSON.stringify(tags));` if you just want to see the content of the array printed (use `JSON.stringify(tags, null, 2)` for pretty print with 2-spaces indent).

Answer (score 5):

You have two options:

1: Use the comma `,` instead of concatenating the strings together, to avoid `toString()` being called and creating `[object Object]`:

```js
var tags = [{"value": "tag1"}, {"value": "tag2"}];
console.log("Tags: ", tags);
```

2: Use `JSON.stringify()` on the object to convert it into a string which can be read:

```js
var tags = [{"value": "tag1"}, {"value": "tag2"}];
console.log("Tags: ", JSON.stringify(tags));
```

Answer (score 4):

When you do `"tags: " + tags`, the [`toString` method of objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) is called in order to do the operation.

Change

```
console.log("tags: " + tags);
```

into

```
console.log("tags: ", tags);
```

so that the `console.log` function of node can do its own more interesting conversion.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `JSON` to log Objects properly if you want to concatenate the strings.

```js
var tags = [{
  "value": "tag1"
}, {
  "value": "tag2"
}];
console.log("tags: " + JSON.stringify(tags))
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why does this happen?

It happens because when you try to concatenate any variable with a string using `+` operator, javascript converts the value of the variable to a string.

Answer (score 1):

**'+'** stringifies the object, thus results [object Object], You need to use JSON.stringify() to convert your object to a JSON string before using console with '+', otherwise use console with ",".